# Error 400 when receiving data from URL parameters en Spring MVC

Tags: spring

I am trying to receive data from an URL with two parameters like this one:

```
http://localhost:80000/xxx/xxx/tickets/search?codprovincia=28&municipio=110000
```

No matter the approach, I am always getting a 400 error, but if I access the URL without the two parameters, the controller returns the view correctly (without the parameters, naturally)

This is the code of my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value =  "/xxx" )
public class BuscadorIncidenciasController extends BaseControllerWeb {

    @RequestMapping("tickets")
    public String tickets(Model model, @RequestParam ("codprovincia") String codprovincia, @RequestParam ("municipio") String municipio, HttpServletRequest request) throws NoAjaxException {

        //...
        return CONST.JSP_VIEW;
    }

...}
```

Extra info: if I use this URL:

```
http://localhost:9081/xxx/xxx/tickets/search/28/790000
```

And this code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value =  "/xxx" )
public class BuscadorIncidenciasController extends BaseControllerWeb {

   @RequestMapping(value = "buscar/{codprovincia}/{municipio}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String buscar(@PathVariable Integer codprovincia, @PathVariable Integer municipio ,Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws NoAjaxException {

        //...
        return CONST.JSP_VIEW;
    }

...}
```

It gets the parameters correctly. The problem is that I have to use the first URL. I have reviewed similar questions about similar issues, and I have implemented the solutions to those issues, but I get the 400 error regardless what I try (add value="xxx=, required=false, and other suggestions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RequestParam, you need to explicitly add 'name' attribute

```
@RequestParam(name = "codprovincia"), @RequestParam (name = "municipio")
```

No need to for HttpServletRequest, unless you have reason

Also, in your 'tickets' method, RequestMapping is not conforming to your URL path.
I think it should be

```
@RequestMapping("/xxx/tickets/search")
```

Cheers!

Comment: The 'name' attribute solved the problem, I was constantly trying with 'value'! Thanks!